# Proving that an infinite dimensional space is closed.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathcal H$ be the subspace of $C([0,1])$ of functions satisfying $f(1-x) = f(x)$ for any $x\in[0,1]$ (these are called even function on $[0,1]$). Then $\mathcal H$ is an infinite dimensional closed subspace of $C([0,1])$.

So I want to have as a basis all the polinomials of the form $(x-1/2)^{i}$ where $i$ is even, but the thing is that I don't know if it could work, and for the other question I was triying to use the pointwise convergence of a series of even functions and then changing this to the series but with $1-x$ as argument of the functions and use the uniqueness of the limit.

So, Can someone help me to prove this assertion, and tell me how to work out with this ideas?, of course if they are right.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do you mean sequences instead of series?

Answer (score 5):

Hints:

1. For each $x \in [0,1]$, $\{f: f(1-x) = f(x)\}$ is closed.
2. An arbitrary intersection of closed sets is closed.
3. Don't worry about a basis: you know enough linearly independent members of $\mathcal H$ to show that it isn't finite-dimensional.

Answer (score 2):

To show it's closed: take $f_n \in \mathcal H$ converging to $f$ and assume by contradiction that $f$ is not even, then there exists $x \in [0,1]$ such that $|f(x)-f(1-x)|\geq \delta >0$.

To show it has infinite dimension: all the even polynomials you wrote belong to $\mathcal{H}$ and that's more than enough for what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, since $C[0,1]$ is a metric space, you can prove it by proving it is sequentially closed. If $f_n\to f$ with $f_n(x)=f_n(1-x)$ for all $n$, then you can fairly directly show that $f(x)=f(1-x)$ by noting that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ and $f_n(1-x)\to f(1-x)$, but those two sequences are known to be identical.

Basically, $C[0,1]$ convergence implies point-wise convergence.